# Gitlab CI - Compute variable name based off another variable

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, gitlab

I am trying to use a variable that is compiled partly from another variable (based off the branch name). I have environmental variables configured in Gitlab like so:

```
Key: s3_bucket_development
Value: https://dev.my-bucket.com

Key: s3_bucket_production
Value: https://prod.my-bucket.com
```

The branch that I am deploying on is called development and the idea is to be able to call the `s3_bucket_development` variable dynamically depending on the branch it is currently on.

So far I have managed to get this far:

```
eval echo $s3_bucket_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
```

Unfortunately the above only outputs `development` to the console, not the value of `$s3_bucket_development` which should be `https://dev.my-bucket.com`

Not sure what i've done wrong here?

Copied a bit from this link [here](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/34273-variable-within-variable.html) but does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
$ s3_bucket_development=test
$ CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=development
$ eval echo \$s3_bucket_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
test
```

You just need to escape the first `$` so it is not parsed as a variable too soon.

---

Also, as this is specific to gitlab ci, I'm thinking you might be solving the issue in the wrong way. In gitlab, you can set gitlab variables and define what to show where.

```yaml
  variables:
    s3_bucket: $s3_bucket
  environment:
    name: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

Comment: I tried that already and it didnt work

Comment: As you see in my example, it works just fine in bash. Check if `s3_bucket_development` is even set by simply `echo $s3_bucket_development` in the ci flow to see if it shows up properly

Comment: not in the gitlab ci :)

Comment: my comment sent hastily, i've amended it